# How to access a plugins component function in app/controller using Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I want to call a function of a component present in plugin.
In my app/xyz_controller i include it as follows
var $components = array('Plugin_name.Component_name'); 
And i call a function as-
$this->Component_name->xyz();
But it doesnot work.
Can any body help me where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this was just your example, but you should refer to plugins and components using camel case instead of underscores:

```
$components = array('PluginName.ComponentName'); 
$this->ComponentName->xyz();
```

This seems to work for me - I am running using Cake 1.3.

Comment: Way better than the other answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried requestAction?, perhaps you could use something like

```
$this->requestAction('/Plugin_name/Component_name/xyz');
```

you can get more information about requestAction at the online documentation

[requestAction - CakePHP Manual](http://book.cakephp.org/view/434/requestAction)

Comment: He isn't trying to load an action. He is trying to call a component function. RequestAction won't do that for him.

Comment: interesting, i came with that after reading [link](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/eimermusic/2009/09/02/designing-a-modular-application-using-cakephp-plugins) wich actually calls a function inside the plugin controller using requestAction. Why it wont work in this case?

Comment: because requestAction can call controller actions but not call controller's component functions. That is the difference.